# Something like a VLOOKUP

Tags: c#, performance

I'm attempting to merge two lists of different objects where a specific field (employeeID) is equal to a specific field[0,0] in another list. My code looks like this:

```
int i = Users.Count() - 1;
int i2 = oracleQuery.Count() - 1;
for (int c = 0; c <= i; c++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d <= i2; d++)
    {
        if (Users[c].getEmployeeID().ToString() == oracleQuery[d][0,0].ToString())
        {
            Users[c].setIDMStatus(oracleQuery[d][0,1].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This works... but it doesn't seem efficient. Any suggestions for more efficient code that will ultimately lead to the Users list containing the new information from the oracleQuery list?

Comment: Whats your datasource? Oracle RDBMS? P.s you are looking for an INNER JOIN which will form part of the db query.

Comment: My datasources are an Oracle DB and data from Active Directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a join with [Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549267.aspx):

```
var matches = Users.Join(oracleQuery, 
                         u => u.getEmployeeId().ToString(), 
                         oq => oq[0,0].ToString(), 
                         (u,oc) => new { User = u, Status = oc[0,1].ToString() });

foreach(var match in matches)
    match.User.setIDMStatus(match.Status);
```

Note that you could eliminate the `ToString()` calls if `getEmployeeId()` and the oracleQuery's `[0,0]` element are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I notice as far as efficiency is that you use the Enumerable.Count() method, which enumerates the results before you loop through again explicitly in your for loops. I think the LINQ implementation will get rid of the pass through the results to count the elements.

I don't know how you feel about using [LINQ QUERY EXPRESSIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics), but this is what I like best:

```cs
var matched = from user in Users
              join item in oracleQuery on user.getEmployeeID().ToString() equals item[0,0].ToString()
              select new {user = user, IDMStatus = item[0,1] };

foreach (var pair in matched) 
{
     pair.user.setIDMStatus(pair.IDMStatus);
}
```

You could also use nested foreach loops (if there are multiple matches and set is called multiple times):

```cs
foreach (var user in Users) 
{
     foreach (var match in oracleQuery.Where(item => user.getEmployeeID().ToString() == item[0,0].ToString()) {
         user.setIDMStatus(match[0,1]);
     }
}
```

Or if there will only be one match for sure:

```cs
foreach (var user in Users) 
{
    var match = oracleQuery.SingleOrDefault(item => user.getEmployeeID().ToString() == item[0,0].ToString()); 
    if (match != null) {
        user.setIDMStatus(match[0,1]);
    }
}
```

I don't think there is any real efficiency problem in what you've written, but you can benchmark it against the implementation in LINQ. I think that using `foreach` or a `Linq query expression` might make the code easier to read, but I think there is not a problem with efficiency. You can also write the LINQ query expression using LINQ method syntax, as was done in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional approach, Steve. I would have done a foreach statement but, for some reason (most likely user error), it didn't want to do that. Something about enumerating... *shrug* Curious question though - wouldn't the select clause in that query generate new objects as opposed to changing existing ones? (Just curious. I honestly don't know.)

Comment: Kind of. This will create a new anonymous object that holds references to your existing objects (unless they are value types, in which case they would be copied). There is some possibility that the compiler could optimize away the object creation, but probably not. The big saving is that you are looping through twice in your code...the call to the Count() extension method will enumerate the results. Then, you loop through it explicitly. With the Linq syntax (my and Copsey's implementations are the same except that I use the query syntax and Copsey uses the method syntax), only one enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes from a databases you could do a join there.  Otherwise, you could sort the two lists and do a merge join that would be faster than what you have now.

However, since C# introduced LINQ there are a lot of ways to do this in code.  Just look up using linq to join/merge lists.